# How to add file (image) in google form by python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, google-forms

I have a problem with python selenium. I want to add a file (image) in google form but I can't do it. I try to use an iframe that switches to a new frame when I click on the upload file button on the first page. There is an error in that it is unable to locate the element (I think its results from my iframe xpath that changes the name every time when I reload the form. What should I do to resolve this problem?

[my code before clicking on the upload file button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r53Sg.png)

[my code after click on upload file button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDb9r.png)

Note: This Google form shuffles the question every time when reloading the page.
I don't sure that I copy the `iframe` xpath correctly.
Thank you for your suggestion